# Inject @PersistenceContext in a custom validator Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to create a custom validator to check if value is unique, but i'm getting `NullPointerExcption` because `session` isn't injected (as well as any other `@Autowired` field). Please, explain me what am i missing here.

**Custom constraint annotation:**

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { UniqueUserValidator.class })
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Unique {

    String message() default "Value is not unique!";

    Class<?> entityType();

    String property();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ TYPE })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @interface List {
       Unique[] value();
    }
}
```

**Custom validator class:**

```
@Component
public class UniqueUserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique, Object> {

   private Unique unique;

   @PersistenceContext
   private Session session;

   @Override
   public void initialize(Unique unique) {
      this.unique = unique;
   }

   @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = true)
   @Override
   public boolean isValid(Object fieldValue, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
      return session
              .createQuery("from " + unique.entityType().getSimpleName() +
                          " where " + unique.property() + "=" + fieldValue)
            .getResultList()
            .isEmpty();
   }
}
```

**Persistence config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

   @Bean
   public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       ... 
       return jpaTransactionManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
       ...
       return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
    ...
    return dataSource;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does `LocalSessionFactoryBean` extend (or implement) `Session`?

Comment: Not directly. This config works fine with all my `@Repository` annotated classes.

Comment: The Spring `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactory` is hibernate aware and will perform injection for your validators. Have you set it up?

Comment: No i didn’t. Gonna look if it helps

Comment: Just declaring `new LocalValidatorFactoryBean()` as `@Bean` doesn't seem to work, could you please specify how to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i found a solution:

1.Declare a validator bean

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

2.Add it to `LocalSessionFactoryBean`

```
Properties customValidator = new Properties();
customValidator.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator());
sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(customValidator);
```